# cluster_selection_method error in dbscan

Tags: python

I am experimenting with clustering using the hdbscan package (0.8.3) in Python.  Reading through the documentation leads me to want to test the different settings for cluster_selection_method (notably, setting it to 'leaf').  When I try to make this change I get:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cluster_selection_method'
```

Here is how I call it:

```
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(algorithm=algorithm,alpha=alpha,metric=metric,min_cluster_size=min_cluster_size \
                       ,min_samples=min_samples,p=p,cluster_selection_method='leaf')
clusterer.fit(data['values'])
```

In this case data['values'] are all 1D arrays with each element having a value of 1.0 or 10.0 as shown below.  Any advice on what might be preventing me from setting the cluster_selection_method would be appreciated.

```
array([  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  10.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
    10.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  10.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  10.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  10.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  10.,   1.,  10.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  10.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
    10.,  10.,  10.,  10.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  10.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  10.,   1.,   1.,  10.,  10.,  10.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  10.,  10.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,  10.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,  10.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
     1.,   1.])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to upgrade to a newer release of hdbscan; the `cluster_selection_method` was a relatively new addition.